# Shopify Redirect.Action.APP Redirects The Whole App

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shopify

I am using Redirect.Action.APP and trying to redirect the user to another component in my app on the admin side. But, i end up go through the auth process again which leads me back to the start of the app. Below is how I am trying to redirect.

```
import { useAppBridge } from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';
import { getSessionToken } from '@shopify/app-bridge-utils';
import { Redirect } from '@shopify/app-bridge/actions';

const app = useAppBridge();

const handleCreate = (app, backdrop) => {
  backdrop.setBackdrop(true);
  const redirect = Redirect.create(app);
  redirect.dispatch(Redirect.Action.APP, `/funnels/create` );
}
```

So, what happens is that, when i press the button that calls handleCreate(app, backdrop) function, it does change the url in the browser but then, it goes to the auth process again on the server side and redirects me back to the start of the application.

What could be the reason?

I have also added a screen recording below to demonstrate what I mean.

[Demonstration video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y4uRwF0KBDB10UtcTGv8HtRQUsDpOVVs/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use API key and shop origin and use this code it will work and will redirect on your child app

```
import { getSessionToken } from '@shopify/app-bridge-utils';
import { Redirect } from '@shopify/app-bridge/actions';
import createApp from '@shopify/app-bridge/development';

const config = {
    apiKey: "SECRET",
    shopOrigin: ORIGIN
};

const app = createApp(config);

const handleCreate = (app, backdrop) => {
  backdrop.setBackdrop(true);
  const redirect = Redirect.create(app);
  redirect.dispatch(Redirect.Action.APP, `/funnels/create` );
}
```